# Static blocks not being rendered

Tags: magento-1.8, static-block

I have a static block defined in magento's backend

```
<p><a href="#"><img src="{{skin url="images/fb_follow.png"}}" alt="fb" /></a> <a href="#"><img src="{{skin url='images/tw_follow.png'}}" alt="fb" /></a> <a href="#"><img src="{{skin url='images/dots_follow.png'}}" alt="fb" /></a> <a href="#"><img src="{{skin url='images/feed.pngs'}}" alt="fb" /></a></p>
```

This is how i call it in one of the templates

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('header_links')->toHtml()
```

The output (it is not rendering the {{}} parts..

```
<p><a href="#"><img src='{{skin url="images/fb_follow.png"}}' alt="fb" /></a> <a href="#"><img src="{{skin url='images/tw_follow.png'}}" alt="fb" /></a> <a href="#"><img src="{{skin url='images/dots_follow.png'}}" alt="fb" /></a> <a href="#"><img src="{{skin url='images/feed.pngs'}}" alt="fb" /></a></p>
```

Comment: {{}}  is not rendered.it convert to url of skin just {{skin url="images/fb_follow.png"}}=www.example.om/skin/frontend/yourpackage/yourtemplate/images/fb_follow.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for bothering, my problem was, i was referencing wrong block in

```
$this->getLayout()
         ->createBlock('cms/block')
         ->setBlockId('header_links')
         ->toHtml();
```

The actual block content was outputed as is without template processing

```
$content = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
               ->setStoreId(
                    Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
               )->load('follow-me')
               ->getContent();
```

Using template processor like in [Mage_Cms_Block_Block::_toHtml](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Block.php) 
solved my problem

```
$html = Mage::helper('cms')
            ->getBlockTemplateProcessor()
            ->filter($content);
```

Comment: If this solved your problem please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that instead of double quotes you use single

```
<img src='{{skin url="images/fb_follow.png"}}' alt="fb" />
```

Because the html output will be like this

```
<img src="http://localhost/skin/frontend/base/default/"fb_follow.png"" alt="fb">
```

Where image path was build not correctly.

Try to use double

```
<img src="{{skin url="images/fb_follow.png"}}" alt="fb" />
```